# How to remove vat from non uk online customers

Tags: php

Trying to remove VAT charge for customers with a shipping address that's outside of the UK.

I've found this code on the basket.php page which i assume adds VAT.

```
    $vat = $settings_obj->getSetting('VAT');
```

As i'm a novice with php i tried  the following code.

```
    if($user->address_shipping->country == 'GB') {
    $vat = $settings_obj->getSetting('VAT');
    }else{
    $vat = $settings_obj->getSetting('VAT' == '0'); 
    }
```

I'm expecting it to remove VAT charge for customers outside the UK, but leave VAT charge for Uk customers.
Any advice would be much appreciated 
Thanks ADyson im new to Stack Overflow so just trying to find my way around.
I dont know who wrote the code but i wonder if you could take look at the below code to see if that's where i need to be.

```
        public function doVAT(){        
        $this->total_vat = number_format( $this->total * VAT, 2 );
```

Comment: Just do `$vat = 0;` for the else case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but that just changes the label to read VAT@ 0% but still adds vat to price.

Comment: Check the documentation for the software you're using. Maybe try using setSetting

Comment: I know Alan Y that you are new, in the future when you post some questions look as much as possible to make us understand in the situation with which you work, for example the software you are using for your system

Comment: Thanks again Sombrero Chicken but i dont know what you mean about Check the documentation for the software you're using.!!! I'm just viewing the code from the source file basket.php in notepad++.

Comment: Well is this code part of a 3rd party commerce product that you're integrating? Or did you write it all yourself? In the former case there might be some documentation or support you can access. In the latter you'll have to look at the source code to see how you can update the VAT value in the settings_obj variable (I'm assuming that's where the calculation happens, but maybe not, again you'll have to check). Since we know exactly nothing about your code except the lines above (which clearly don't do the VAT calcs) we can't easily help you

Comment: Thanks ADyson there's no 3rd party integration. The code wasn't written by me as i'm a novice when it comes to php web development. I understand html/css but not php. I have however found more code which could be where the calculation happens.

Comment: static public function getVat( $price, $wrap=true ){

  //convert percent to decimal
  $vat = "0.".VAT;
  $val = number_format( $vat * $price, 2, '.', '' );
  $ret = number_format( $price + $val, 2, '.', '' );
  if( $wrap )
   $ret = "<span class=\"price-vat\">( £" . $ret . " inc. VAT      )</span>";

  return $ret;
 }

Comment: So now you need to find a way to set the `VAT` variable before you run that function. You'll have to find where it's declared and set. Do you know who wrote the code? Perhaps they can help you

Comment: P.s. if you have extra code please put it in the question itself (using the edit button), it's very hard to read when it's in the comments and some people might not notice it

Comment: Thanks ADyson im new to Stack Overflow so just trying to find my way around. I dont know who wrote the code but i wonder if you could take look at the above last code block to see if that's where i need to be.

Comment: Like I said before, you need to work out where in the code `VAT` is declared and if there is a function of the class which allows you to alter it. It look like it may be a constant so you may have some more work to do if you want to support more than one VAT jurisdiction.

Comment: Thanks for all your help ADyson but i'm struggling to find the code to change, so it ;looks like i will have to get someone in to take at look.

Comment: If you get a proper IDE instead of notepad you might be able to trace it back. Try Visual Studio Code for a free one. There are others too.

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks again ADyson.